# .htaccess configuration to allow access from certain IPs and by logging in without access to .htaccess for anyone

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a .htaccess file for a folder. Users from certain IPs and logged in user (from certain groups) are supposed to be able to access all the files in the folder except for the .htaccess file (which should be unaccessible to everyone). I'm just stuck here. This is what I've got so far:

```
<FILES .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FILES>

Order allow,deny
Deny from all
# Location of users file
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd
# Location of usergroups file
AuthGroupFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htgroup
# Name of the prompt
AuthName "Enter password"
AuthType Basic
# Required usergroup to access content
Require group group1
# Allow access from IP 1 without login
Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.www
# Allow access from IP 2 without login
Allow from jjj.kkk.lll.mmm
Satisfy any

Options +Indexes
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's (finally) the working solution:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!\.htaccess).*$">

AuthType Basic
# Name of the prompt
AuthName "Enter user name andd password"
# Users file location
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd
# Usergroups file location
AuthGroupFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htgroup
# Required group for authentication
Require group group_name

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
# Allow access from this IP without login
Allow from aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
Satisfy any

</FilesMatch>
```